# Switch Case Vs. If.. Else (specific task)

Tags: php, if-statement, switch-statement

I have 3 arrays that could be set or not. Their keys are strings.

Would it be more efficient this If... Else

```
if( isset( $arrayA[ $id ] ) )
{
    if( isset( $arrayB[ $id ] ) )
    {
        if( isset( $arrayC[ $id ] ) )
        {
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if( isset( $arrayC[ $id ] ) )
        {
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
}
else
{
    if( isset( $arrayB[ $id ] ) )
    {
        if( isset( $arrayC[ $id ] ) )
        {
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if( isset( $arrayC[ $id ] ) )
        {
        }
    }
}
```

or a Switch... Case like this?

```
$ABC = ( isset( $arrayA[ $id ] ) ? "1" : "0" ) . ( isset( $arrayB[ $id ] ) ? "1" : "0" ) . ( isset( $arrayC[ $id ] ) ? "1" : "0" );

switch( $ABC )
{
    case "001":
    case "010":
    case "011":
    case "100":
    case "101":
    case "110":
    case "111":
}
```

Note that "000" case will never occur in my script.

Suppose I know combinations' frequency.
More frequent ->
"110"
"111"
"010"
"100", "101", "001"
"011"
<- Less frequent

Anyway "110" and "111" occur almost always. "010" could occur 1 time per 10^4 or 10^5 times the cumulative occurrence "110"+"111".

Would this If... else a better solution?

```
if( isset( $arrayA[ $id ] ) and isset( $arrayB[ $id ] ) )
{
        if( isset( $arrayC[ $id ] ) )
        {
        }
        else
        {
        }
}
else
{
    $ABC = ( isset( $arrayA[ $id ] ) ? "1" : "0" ) . ( isset( $arrayB[ $id ] ) ? "1" : "0" ) . ( isset( $arrayC[ $id ] ) ? "1" : "0" );

    switch( $ABC )
    {
        case "001":
        case "010":
        case "011":
        case "100":
        case "101":
    }
}
```

Comment: Who cares? It's micro-optimization. Just don't.

Comment: its more efficient in this case switch because the JVM loads the value to compare and iterates through the value table to find a match. For many cases is better Switch

Comment: It is not Java but PHP and for this kind of code, I would consider readability to be of higher importance than premature optimization. So choose the one, which is more readable and comment if necessary.

Comment: I think Switch would be readable. My problem is that I have to face a free  (exec)time-limited webserver and this code will be a small part of great script. That's why I'm looking for the best (micro-)optimization. Yes, it is PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Go for `switch`. Its more readable in this case and you can track the outputs more easily than the series of `if-else` you deployed. The last thing you want is make you and whoever else is going to work on your code make confused with the help of unnecessary complexity. Keep it simple.

Comment: No one is going to work on my code. It's spare time programming. I understand the matter of complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to execution time, your solution with one single switch statement would be preferable, as it doesn't need 3 comparisons to get to the "right" method. The hierarchy of the switch statement doesn't really matter, but I guess for such simple computations difference wouldn't be significant if you use only switch or combined switch.

You could time the operation time for your *best case* scenario with the last method. Anyway only using switch statements would produce exactly the same **computation complexity** in all three cases.

Comment: Good idea. I will report the results if I would time the operation time.